# Do I need to manually delete or manage this unique_ptr

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, integer, managed

Do I need to manage this array in any way or will the unique_ptr take care of it? I have read that if arry gets assigned a new value then it will no longer be managed. I am new to this don't understand it very well.

```
int main() {

    int i = 0;
    int maxSpaceSize = 10;    
    unique_ptr<int[]> arry (new int[maxSpaceSize]());

    for (i = 0; i < maxSpaceSize; i++) {
        arry[i] = i;
        cout << arry[i];
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My goal in this is to make and understand dynamic arrays with automatic garbage collection. At some point I would ask the user to define the size of the array and that would be assigned to maxSpaceSize.

Thanks for helpful input.

Comment: Ummm... [`arry.reset(nullptr)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) ?

Answer (score 3):

> Do I need to manage this array in any way or will the unique_ptr take care of it?

The `std::unique_ptr` will take care. There's a specialization for raw array deleters to call `delete [] pointee;`

> I have read that if arry gets assigned a new value then it ***will no longer be managed***.

That's wrong information (emphasis mine).

The [*assignment operator overload*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D) of `std::unique_ptr` will delete the old pointee, and further take care of the new one.

So whenever you write something like

```
maxSpaceSize = 50;
arry = unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[maxSpaceSize]);
```

that behavior will apply.

<sub>See [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5bbf0180bc291847)</sub>